# Is there a easier method to find mean and variance of a function of normal variable

Tags: probability, statistics

Assuming that there's a function $Y=f(X)=0.5X^{0.3}$, where $X$ is a normal random variable with mean $\mu$ and $\sigma$, what's the best method to find mean and variance of $Y$?

My approach is to find the derived distribution of $Y$, first express $X=(Y/0.5)^{1/0.3}$ and $$f_Y(y)=\frac{f_X((Y/0.5)^{1/0.3})}{0.3\times 0.5((Y/0.5)^{1/0.3})^{0.3-1}}$$

Now we have the pdf of $Y$ thus we have mean and variance. My question is, is there an easier method to do this?

Comment: Use the cumulative distribution function of $Y$.

Comment: Hi: If you take the log of both sides of your expression, then you can show that log(Y) is normal. This means that Y is lognormal. That should get you some distance in obtaining the distribution for Y.

Comment: @markleeds Hi, Why log($0.5 X^{0.3}$) a normal distribution, if $X$ is normal

Comment: @FedePoncio Could you please be more specific?

Comment: @Maskoff: Maybe you're right ? I'll have to think about it some more but I don't have time right now.  You can move the 0.3 down in front of the log ( because $log(X^{a}) = a log(X) $) but still that's not get you get you much.